# Where are docs for typescript on the generic that functions take?

Tags: typescript

For example, how do I know what `Array.prototype.find()` takes? How do I know what `T` in `Foo.find<T>()...` should be?

Comment: They're documented in `lib.es6.d.ts` (and other `lib.*.d.ts` files in your `typescript\lib` directory).

Comment: `T` is a generic-type parameter, **it can be anything** (unless there's a generic-type constraint - which will be in the declaration in the `*.d.ts` file).

Comment: @Dai is correct. Note that, if you are explicitly specifying the generics, when _calling_ a function, you are usually doing something wrong.

Comment: @AluanHaddad There are plenty of times where type-inference can't be used for specifying generic type parameters, such as when specifying a return-type.

Comment: If a function declares a generic that is only related to its return type it often indicates a serious design flaw or a misunderstanding of the language. As all types are erased, a function like `function f<T>(): T` is suspicious to say the least. There are rare exceptions, very rare.

Comment: How about for React? It seems like I need to pass types to useState in order for Typescript compiler to not complain. Am I suppose to always look at DefinitelyTyped for that?

Comment: Use state is supposed to infer the types from the value that you pass through it